# cannot find the declaration of element 'linearlayout'

Tags: android

I am new to Android and learning with a book.But here comes the problem. When I decided to add a folder named layout_larger and copied the file named `activity_one_page_or_two.xml` to `layout_larger`, unfortunately I occurred the 
`error : Error:(4, 43) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element LinearLayout`.No idea why it comes. Anyone could give me a hand?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Anderson, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question needs a little work on the formatting to make it more readable; for example, consider using the code markup (backticks or four spaces) for the error line, and consider adding image descriptions where it says "enter image description here".

Comment: Your 'double-quotes', they look a bit styled (custom font?). Did you copy the code from a book? Retype the double quotes yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your current layout directory name **layout_large** this is incorrect

correct name of directory is **layout-large**

i hope your problem is resolve.

Answer (score 1):

When providing alternative resources, the folders should use a "-" as a separator. You are using "_". Try renaming your folder to "layout-large".

Answer (score 1):

your first and last resource to get knowledge about android development is [official developer site](https://developer.android.com/index.html).

According to your question look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).

Solution : change your directory name like this **layout-large insted of layout_large**.