# Android cannot find declaration of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, element, android-relativelayout, declaration

I am creating different layouts to support different screen sizes.So I created folders like layout-small,layout-large and so on.But I am stuck with the error cannot find the declaration of element RelativeLayout. How do I solve this?

Comment: maybe you can share your code? & makesure that your id of RelativeLayout is same

Comment: Do I have to do include something in Manifest file

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972450/cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-linearlayout maybe same issue

Comment: I checked that but that is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

@jobin , android till now does not allow to create seperate layout folders/packages , so please create all your layouts in the layout folder only, u can use prefix or postfix tags to differentiate between layouts.

for ex
activity_main_small , 
activity_main_big   ,
activity_main_verybig

but do remember to keep all layout Xmls under the single layout folder provided .