# can not find the declaration of element "Android support constraint ConstraintLayout"

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know what type of error is this?

Image One

[image]

Image Two

[image]

I've even noticed that layout place was in `res` folder now it's changed by itself in java folder? Why is that happening to my application? and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to the build.gradle (app)

If you are using AndroidStudio 3.x.x

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

or below

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: my android studio is 2.3.3  but tried you comment but didn't work :(

Comment: you need to download the [ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 from support repository in android sdk](https://prnt.sc/ho1w9l)

Answer (score 0):

must of those problem come from long destination of your project

try to move your project to  Ex : 
 C:\myprojet

Comment: i find some answer that can help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972450/cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-linearlayout