# Android layout resource files not refreshing after upgrading Android Studio to Version 3.6.1

Tags: validation, android-layout

I added two textfields to a layout file.  When I execute the app, the fields do not show up.  I get the old layout, the one prior to making my updates.  I have tried the following suggestions:

```
clean rebuild clean
delete catches and restart
Completely exiting and restarting Android Studio
```

So I decided to make sure that my XLM files were valid.  When I validate them,  I get this error:  cannot find the declaration of element 'Scrollview".  Each XML file got this error on its top layout view - RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, and Scrollview. I am not sure how to correct this error.   I assume this is why my layout is not refreshing.,

Answer (score 0):

This may be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972450/cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-linearlayout)

It may have to do with a change with your directory name

Comment: I thought about that that maybe the files were place under the wrong directory.  I verified that the files are under the project directory.

Comment: Is there any chance that the directory name changed? In the example, the - was changed to a _ fro example

Comment: I agree with you,  I think that I am dealing with a misplaced file. I will delete one of my XML files within Android Studio.  Then I will add it back using a copy/paste function while in Android Studio to make sure it is owned by Android Studio's project directory.  Then I will validate it again to see if the error disappears.

Comment: I am relatively new to Android Studio.  Where do I verify the value of the 'official' Project Directory - in Project Settings, Project Structure, et...?